# Inequality of lipschitz smooth function

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ be a $\rho$-lipschitz smooth function, meaning that
$$
||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \leq \rho ||x-y||, \forall x,y \in dom(f)
$$

Is following inequality true?

$$
\nabla f(x) \leq \nabla f(y) + \rho ||x-y||
$$

How do I remove norm from the inequation and show that it is true?

It comes to me when I'm reading following math in an article

[image]

Comment: The norm on the left is just the absolute value, seeing your gradient lives in $\mathbb{R}$, so it's pretty straightforward if you remember what $|a| \leq b$ means.

Comment: @BrunoB, What happens if $f:R^n \rightarrow R$, so the gradient lives in $R^n$ ?

Comment: The problem lies in what meaning you would give to $u \leq v$ for vectors, as well as the inability for $\nabla f(x)$ and $\rho\|x - y\|$ to live in the same space and thus be added together. Maybe the $\nabla$ in the text you quote is supposed to designate the divergence instead of the gradient?

Comment: @BrunoB, bruh you are genius... thank you very much. One last question, for the inequality in the last figure to be hold, does the gradient have to live in $R$? It is weird because $w$ and $w_i$ are vectors.

Comment: @BrunoB, and would you please post above answers in the answer section so that I can mark your comment as the answer

Comment: By the way you should always mention the source of whatever you quote directly. Not just to give credit to the author (still important), but more importantly this can help users who have access to the book or paper to potentially help you more adequately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to write inequalities with $\nabla f$ and for it to coexist and be summed with $\rho \|x - y\|$, it would need to have real values to begin with, in which case the left-side's norm is just the absolute value and it's fairly straightforward to go from the first inequality to the second.

The problem with that is that this can't apply to gradients for $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with $n \geq 2$ since then the gradient of $f$ would be $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued and there's no "natural" meaning for $u \leq v$ when $u$ and $v$ are vectors. Yet that's not just a problem with what you wrote yourself but also with the text you quoted... Maybe the author used the $\nabla$ symbol for the divergence instead of the gradient?